# What happens when you get rid of a singularity?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, speed-of-light, causality, thought-experiment

There's a pretty common physics chestnut about what would happen if the sun just up and disappeared. "How long would it take for us to notice?" The answer is of course roughly eight minutes-- that's how long it would take for the last emitted photon to reach us, at which point the sky would suddenly go dark. That's also how long it would take for Earth to suddenly fall out of orbit, the propagation speed of gravity being the same as light.

The thing I'm wondering is this; let's say that instead of the sun, we're orbiting a black hole-- at a safe distance, of course. Now let's say that the singularity inside the event horizon vanishes. Maybe it tunnels off somewhere, or maybe we snap our fingers and it's just gone, whatever. If we're eight light-minutes from the singularity (eight light minutes from where the center of the star would have been if it hadn't collapsed, really), how long will it take for us to fall out of orbit? Still just eight minutes? Or will the change in gravity be forced to follow the geodesics of space, and never actually escape the event horizon?-- will we never fall out of orbit at all?

Comment: This cannot be answered because mass/energy cannot just vanish. You are proposing a situation that violates the laws of physics then expecting the laws of physics to give you an answer.